# ContentProvider openFile - how to delete file

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I implemented my own ContentProvider and overloaded the openFile method. Here an example that stores a set of persons given by first and last name. For each person you can store an image/photo.

```
public class PersonTable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "persons";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " COLUMN_FIRSTNAME)";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(database);
    }
}

public class PersonDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "person.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        PersonTable.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        PersonTable.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}

public class PersonContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static final int URI_TYPE_PERSONS = 1;
    private static final int URI_TYPE_SINGLE_PERSON = 2;

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "eu.level12.contentprovider";
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "person";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BASE_PATH);

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, URI_TYPE_PERSONS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", URI_TYPE_SINGLE_PERSON);
    }

    private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int deletedRows = 0;
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (uriType) {
        case URI_TYPE_PERSONS:
            // ToDo: delete all persons at once
            break;
        case URI_TYPE_SINGLE_PERSON:
            String locationID = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            final String where = PersonTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + locationID;

            deletedRows = database.delete(PersonTable.TABLE_NAME, where, null);

            if (deletedRows > 0) {
                deleteFile(uri);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            }

            break;
        }

        return deletedRows;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);

        Uri result = null;

        switch (uriType) {
        case URI_TYPE_PERSONS:
            SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            long id = database.insert(PersonTable.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            result = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(result, null);

            break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        Cursor result = null;
        int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case URI_TYPE_PERSONS:
            // ToDo: query all persons at once
            break;
        case URI_TYPE_SINGLE_PERSON:
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();

            SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            builder.setTables(PersonTable.TABLE_NAME);
            String where = PersonTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id;
            builder.appendWhere(where);
            SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            result = builder.query(database, projection, selection,
                    selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        }

        if (result != null)
            result.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext());

        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dir
        File directory = cw.getDir(BASE_PATH, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        directory.mkdirs();

        long id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
        File path = new File(directory, String.valueOf(id));

        int imode = 0;
        if (mode.contains("w")) {
            imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WRITE_ONLY;
            if (!path.exists()) {
                try {
                    path.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (mode.contains("r"))
            imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY;
        if (mode.contains("+"))
            imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_APPEND;

        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(path, imode);
    }

    private void deleteFile(Uri uri) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext());

        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dir
        File directory = cw.getDir(BASE_PATH, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        File file = new File(directory, id);

        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
    }
}
```

Now, within an Activity, I create a sample person and an image that is associated with that person. Later on, you could delete the person including its image. But how to delete just the image, without deleting the person itself?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // create a sample person
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PersonTable.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, "Max");
        values.put(PersonTable.COLUMN_NAME, "Moritz");

        // insert the sample person into DB
        Uri uri = cr.insert(PersonContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);

        // add an image for that person (image is stored on file system)
        try {
            OutputStream stream = cr.openOutputStream(uri);

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            stream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Option 1: delete person --> will also delete image on file system
        // (see PersonContentProvider.delete)
        cr.delete(uri, null, null);

        // Option 2: delete only the image, without deleting the person
        // How ????????????
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand what doesn't it have to do with openFile

Comment: You can store any binary file for a record that is then associated with it. Use getContentResolver.openOutputStream(uri....). And if you delete that record, you get a delete call into your ContentProvider and you could delete the binary file as well. But I don't want to delete the record, but only the file.

Comment: use ContentProvider.delete method with or without "selection" param e. g.  "kind=record|file|both"

Comment: That's a good idea. I will update my post above to show an example in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a static method in all my ContentProvider implementations. The Uri is the entry/row that should be deleted (example: /location/1) and the base-path is the one of the ContentProvider itself. I invoke that method in ContentProvider.delete(...).

```
protected static boolean deleteFile(Uri uri, String basePath,
        Context context, boolean notifyChange) {

    if (uri == null || context == null)
        return false;

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);

    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dir
    File directory = cw.getDir(basePath, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    File file = new File(directory, id);

    if (file.exists()) {
        boolean result = file.delete();
        if (notifyChange && result)
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        if (result)
            Log.d(TAG, "Deleted file for " + uri.toString());

        return result;
    }

    return false;
}
```